# How do change saved file name in request for loop (Url to PDF)

Tags: python, filenames, python-requests-html

I want to use a for loop to access urls and save them as PDF files in a google colab file using request (paid API key). I want to individually name my files pdf+idx. I have tried the following but it does not work. Can anyone help?

Thank you!

```
for idx, row in unique_df.iterrows():
  r = requests.post(url, json = {
    'url': row['TrackTrace'],
    'FileName': 'pdf'+idx,
    'viewportWidth': 1200
  }, headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token: {}'.format(apiKey)
  })
open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Url2PDF/PDFS/FileName.pdf', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate ("add") strings together with `+`, just first you have to make a string from `idx` as `str(idx)`:

```
for idx, row in unique_df.iterrows():
  r = requests.post(url, json = {
    'url': row['TrackTrace'],
    'FileName': 'pdf'+idx,
    'viewportWidth': 1200
  }, headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Token: {}'.format(apiKey)
  })
  with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Url2PDF/PDFS/FileName'+str(idx)+'.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```